# Can you assemble a cube out of 2000 other cubes?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

In more rigorous terms, does there exist some $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

$$x^{3} = \sum_{i=1}^{2000} a_{i}^{3}$$

for $a_{i} \in \mathbb{N}$? Note that the $a_{i}$'s need not be distinct.

After tinkering around in Mathematica for a couple of hours I'm beginning to believe the answer is no, but I have no idea why, or what theory or theories would suggest as such. (I also tried to use Fermat's Last Theorem but that was silly so I stopped doing that.) Any answers would be appreciated - thanks in advance.

Comment: You can always take $x=a_i=0$.

Comment: @ElioJoseph I think by $\mathbb N$ OP means positive integers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to satisfy the equation.  You can start with the known $3^3+4^3+5^3=6^3$  If you take $12^3=1728 \ 6 \times 6 \times 6$ cubes, then replace $(2000-1728)/2$ of them with $3^3+4^3+5^3$ you will have a solution.  This does not guarantee you can build a $72 \times 72 \times 72$ cube from these pieces.  There will be many other solutions to the equation.

Added:  a way to make a collection that can form a cube is to again start with $1728\ 6 \times 6 \times 6$ cubes which you can form into a $72 \times 72 \times 72$  cube.  We can replace one of the $6 \times 6 \times 6$ cubes with $8\ 3 \times 3 \times 3$ cubes or $27\ 2 \times 2 \times 2$ cubes.  If we replace $4$ of the size $6$ cubes with size $2$ ones and $24$ with size $3$ ones, we add $4\cdot 26+24 \cdot 7=272$ pieces for a total of $2000$.